# Looking for additional explanation for spring security setup

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

My requirements are pretty simple :

- I want for all my links to be accessible only if user is logged in
- If the user is not logged in, redirect him to login page

Thinking to myself shouldn't be too hard. I did this before, but programming myself. This time we're doing a new project and I decided to give it a go.

Beside spring dependencies I use in my project spring security dependencies :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springsecurity-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Where `${org.springsecurity-version}` is `3.0.4.RELEASE`. Here is important part of my `web.xml` :

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
       classpath:security-app-context.xml
       /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
   </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

My `security-app-context.xml` :

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <http once-per-request="false" auto-config="false">

        <!-- All other resources to require users to have user role USER_ROLE to view -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <!-- Don't apply any filters to the login form either, we want unauthenticated users to be able to see this -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" filters="none" />

        <anonymous />
        <http-basic />

        <form-login login-page="/login"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <!-- I've defined a custom UserDetails service to lookup users in my db using me own implementation -->
    <beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="fully.qualified.class.name.MyUserDetailsService">
        <!--<beans:property name="userServ" ref="UserService" /> -->
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Here is my controller (displaying dashboard page which I want only logged in users to see) :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("main")
public class DashboardController {

    @RequestMapping("start")
    public String getDashboard(){
        return "dashboard";
    }

}
```

My login controller (method which displays login):

```
@RequestMapping("/login")
    public String getLogin(){
        return "login";
    }
```

I have no exceptions. It's just not working how I described it above. Only thing that is not working properly, I can't opet login page. I get message that it cannot be found. But when I change my login controller method to :

```
@RequestMapping("/login/me")
        public String getLogin(){
            return "login";
        }
```

My login page does open. I'm not sure what am I doing wrong. I found couple of pages, each has something but I couldn't pick this up. I looked at :

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html
http://blog.richardadamdean.com/?p=213
https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/spring-security-and-wicket-auth-roles.html
http://springinpractice.com/2008/10/11/hashing-and-salting-passwords-with-spring-security-2/
http://www.codercorp.com/blog/spring/security-spring/writing-custom-userdetailsservice-for-spring-security.html
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: What is your Dispatcher Servlet mapping?

Answer (score 2):

It's a few years since I used Spring Security, but there's a ROLE_ANONYMOUS or something similar, that unauthenticated users get, which you should assign to your login page in the security XML.

Also I would move your line containing the login access above the generic /* one as I think it's first come first served. This is all based off a rusty memory though, so apologies if it's no good.

Comment: True, they will be evaluated in the order listed. Configure like this:<http once-per-request="false" auto-config="false">  <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"><intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER"><anonymous /><form-login login-page="/login"/><http-basic></http>